# Where in the user profile are the Firefox search engine choices stored?

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, user-profiles

We have a large number of user profiles that were created on Ubuntu 10.04 and they had access to Google as a choice in the search bar and Google was the provider for queries typed into the super bar.

When logging into these same profiles from Mint 15 client machines, the Google search option does not exist for these users, as is the default for Mint.

This setting seems to be user specific, but not a part of the FireFox profile? It seems if it were a part of the FF profile, it would "just work" on Mint for these profiles, so I suspect the configuration may be stored somewhere else in the user's profile?

Could someone please tell me where in a user's profile the search engine options are set? We would like to set this once, and then drop this configuration into everyones profile so all of our users don't have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)

> The search.sqlite file and searchplugins folder store the search
>   engines that are available in the Firefox Search bar.

So although a Linux Mint version of Firefox seems to change existing user profiles, you could just install the application and afterwards swap the corresponding files within the clients' profile folders with your Google-search-enabled ones.

Comment: It seems like something else must be going on though. Once you set the engine list it stays. Using an old engine list should also stay.  If mint really is overwriting FireFox profiles, there must be some flag that it uses to decide if it's done that yet or not. If that's the case, we can simply set that flag on everyone's profile.